# Solve GLPK from .mod file in Python Pulp

Tags: python, glpk, pulp

Its possible to solve a problem from a .mod file using Pulp?

In the documentation there's nothing about it.

is initiated like this:

```
prob = LpProblem("linearProblem", LpMinimize)
```

I want something like this:

```
prob = LpProblem("/home/problem.mod","linearProblem", LpMinimize)
```

I'm using python3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and No.

From within Pulp the GLPK solve call is fixed to the lp format (which is used when creating a problem with Pulp).
When you look into the [sourcecode](https://github.com/coin-or/pulp/blob/master/src/pulp/solvers.py) of Pulp you see that there is just a simple commandline call to start GLPK (starting line 355 and excecuted in line 369 or 371).

You can make basically the same call with

```
proc = ["glpsol", "--math", your_mod_file, "-o", your_solution_file]
```

When the operation is done you can read the solution back in the Pulp structure with the Pulp function

```
pulp.solver.GLPK.readsol(your_solution_file)
```